# MongoDB/JS Create Object Key from String

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a string such as :
key = "person.name.first"

Is it possible to convert that to...

```
{
    person: {
        name: {
            first: '????'
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a small `recursive` utility function to achieve this in java script

```
var key = "person.name.first".split("\.");
var obj = {};

function create(o,index){
  if(index > key.length-1) return;
  o[key[index]] = {};
  index++;
  create(o[key[index-1]],index);
}

// Call the recursive function:
create(obj,0);
```

Then you could set the value as: `person.name.first = "value";`

If you would want to set the values, or dynamically set the type of each field such as an array or object, you could have an mapping array, which holds the type for each field and could be read during the creation.